# play-json: JsNull is not equal to JsString(null), how to get around this issue?

Tags: json, scala, play-json

I'm working on some largeish JSON output. We've got a bunch of tests to check the output. We've created the tests by having a copy of the JSON on disk, performing a `Json.parse()` on the `InputStream` and comparing that to the JsObject we have build in memory.

This worked well until I started converting some of our `Writes` to using the functional syntax (i.e. instead of overriding the `writes` method in the trait, use the builders).

Suddenly, tests started failing: complaining about `null` fields that were not equal.

Apparently, when using functional syntax, an `Option[String]` will convert to a `JsString(null)` instead of `JsNull`. This is not noticeable In the stringified version.

Consider the following snippet, using

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.7.4"
```

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

object FooBar {

  case class Foo(option: Option[String])

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val classic: OWrites[Foo] = new OWrites[Foo] {
      override def writes(f: Foo): JsObject = Json.obj("foo" -> f.option)
    }

    val dsl: OWrites[Foo] = (__ \ "foo").write[String].contramap(foo => foo.option.orNull)

    val json_classic = Json.toJsObject(Foo(None))(classic)
    val json_dsl = Json.toJsObject(Foo(None))(dsl)


    val json_parse = Json.parse("""{"foo":null}""")

    val string_classic = Json.prettyPrint(json_classic)
    val string_dsl = Json.prettyPrint(json_dsl)

    println(
      s"""Result is:
         |json_dsl       == json_classic : ${json_dsl == json_classic} // (expect true)
         |json_dsl       == json_parse   : ${json_dsl == json_parse} // (expect true)
         |json_classic   == json_parse   : ${json_classic == json_parse} // (expect true)
         |string_classic == string_dsl   : ${string_classic == string_dsl} // (expect true)
         |""".stripMargin)

    println(s"classic:\n$string_classic")
    println(s"dsl:\n$string_dsl")

  }
}
```

Actual output is

```
Result is:
json_dsl       == json_classic : false // (expect true)
json_dsl       == json_parse   : false // (expect true)
json_classic   == json_parse   : true // (expect true)
string_classic == string_dsl   : true // (expect true)

classic:
{
  "foo" : null
}
dsl:
{
  "foo" : null
}
```

When debugging, you'll see that the classic create a wrapper object with a Tuple `("foo", JsNull)`, whereas the dsl creates a wrapper with a Tuple `("foo", JsString(null))`.

It seems that the intended way of the dsl is to use `writeNullable` in this case, but it feels odd that it works this way.

I'd either expect `JsString(null) == JsNull` to be true, or that the dsl would catch the `null` value and prevent a `JsString` from being created.

Am I doing something totally misguided?

I would just rewrite to `.writeNullable[String]`, which will remove the field from the JSON, but we have a schema in place that requires the field to be present:

```
...
"properties": {
  ...
  "foo": {
    "oneOf": [
      {"type": "string"},
      {"type": "null"}
    ]
  },
  ...
}
...
"required": [ "foo" ],
```

This is part of an API, so changing it will take time.

To clarify: String representation is correct in all cases. I'm only interested in the in-memory representation of the `JsValue` so I can use its equality during testing.

Comment: P.S.: I know I could just use the classic notation for this case so that it does what it should. The reason I'm trying to move to the DSL is that it has a more stable output of the order of fields. This is not strictly needed but helps human viewing of JSON files to quickly find specific keys.

Comment: so... you want `"null"` in quotes instead of `null` (like it should be) because of legacy API choices, right?

Comment: No, I don't want `"null"`, I want the actual JSON `null` value. `"foo"` in this case can either be a `string` or a JSON `null` and must be present. The classic `Writes` creates the (correct) `JsNull` representation in the in-memory model. The dsl creates a `JsString` albeit with a `null` value, not a string `"null"`. (i.e. when you Stringify both the classic and the dsl version the representations are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```scala
val dsl: OWrites[Foo] = (__ \ "foo").writeOptionWithNull[String]
  .contramap(_.option)
```

Or, if using an older play-json version that doesn't have `writeOptionWithNull`:

```scala
val dsl: OWrites[Foo] = (__ \ "foo").write[JsValue]
  .contramap(_.option match {
    case None => JsNull
    case Some(string) => JsString(string)
  })
```

Note, `play.api.libs.json.JsNull`, and `null`, are two completely different and unrelated concepts, and should never be confused or mixed. The convention across the whole Scala ecosystem in Scala-only APIs is to never, ever use `null`, to the extent where most libraries simply pretend that it doesn't even exist. So, you won't find many Scala libraries that do null checks, they just assume everything is non null, and the moment you start using null, you're in the wild west of untested and unsupported edge cases. The only time you use or deal with nulls is if working with a Java API, because they use nulls, and the convention there is to wrap anything that can produce a `null` in `Option` as early as possible, and unwrap `Option` using `orNull` as late as possible, so that at least internally in the Scala code that doesn't directly interface to Java code, everything is using `Option`, rather than `null`. But play-json is designed for Scala use only, so like the rest of the Scala-only ecosystem, it just assumes `null` doesn't exist.

Of course, in json, `null` does exist, and there may be valid reasons to use it (especially when integrating with other systems that require it). So play-json does model it, but it models it in a very strongly typed way - nothing will ever automatically go from being `null` in Scala to being `null` in JSON, it's always very explicit, this is in line with Scala being strongly typed. Also, use of `null` in JSON doesn't tend to be that common, so most of the default methods (ie, the `writeNullable` method) map `Option` to a non-existent value, so you have to be a little more explicit when you want to write a JSON `null`, as shown above.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your tests in REPL with Play-JSON 2.7.4:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Foo(option: Option[String])

val classic: OWrites[Foo] = new OWrites[Foo] {
  override def writes(f: Foo): JsObject = Json.obj("foo" -> f.option)
}

val dsl: OWrites[Foo] = (__ \ "foo").write[String].contramap(foo => foo.option.orNull)


val json_classic = Json.toJsObject(Foo(None))(classic)
val json_dsl = Json.toJsObject(Foo(None))(dsl)

val json_classic = Json.toJsObject(Foo(None))(classic)
// json_classic: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"foo":null}

val json_dsl = Json.toJsObject(Foo(None))(dsl)
// json_dsl: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"foo":null}
```

The inequality between `json_classic` and `json_dsl` is something else, but the JSON representation is consistent in both cases, even if the `foo.option.orNull` is unsafe/weird for me.

On the otherwise, if you want to consider `"null"` as `null`, you can override the default `Reads[String]` where this specific behaviour is wanted.

```
scala> val legacyStrReads: Reads[Option[String]] =
     |   Reads.optionWithNull(Reads.StringReads).map {
     |     case Some("null") => None
     |     case other => other
     |   }
legacyStrReads: play.api.libs.json.Reads[Option[String]] = play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$6@138decb1

scala> Json.toJson("null").validate(legacyStrReads)
res9: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Option[String]] = JsSuccess(None,)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to dig into this. You are correct, I'm not talking about the representation of the JSON, it is as you found correct. I'm specifically talking about the inequality between `json_classic` and `json_dsl`. Since I don't want to stringify and then parse again to get the same in memory model to check equality. I also don't want to use `String` equality. Note that I'm _not_ trying to get a `String` representation of `null` (i.e. `"null"`), it must be the actual `null` value.

Comment: To clarify: I don't want to use `String` equality of two JSON objects because the order of keys in both JSON strings might (or actually will) be different between consecutive runs. This means that using `String` equality will give false negatives. So I want to run tests using the `JsValue#equals(JsValue)` method.

Comment: P.S. I agree that the `.orNull` on `Option` is awkward. As stated: I'm working towards changing the API to not have this field mandatory, but that takes time. I'm also interested in figuring out what `JsString(null)` means and if it is a bug that this representation gets created this way.

Comment: `JsString` (as other)  is expecting a non-null value, there this is violated

Comment: Fair point. So basically you're saying the DSL should not be used to output fields with a `null` value?

Comment: Right, rather use options